# Is there a way in ansible to access variables with multiple keys like in hosts.yml in other file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

In hosts.yml we can declare variables like that:

```
group1_hosts:
  hosts:
    host1:
    host2:
      var1: var1val1
      var2: var2val2
```

Then we have this variable available on two hosts - multiple keys can have same values.

Is this possible to declare variables in `group_vars/all.yml` in similar way:

```
variables:
  host1:
  host2:
    var1: var1val1
  host3:
  host4:
    var1: var1val2
```

and then access them like - `{{ variables[inventory_hostname].var1 }}`

If the idea is not clear - I would like to avoid setting two variables for every environment hosts in many files. Instead I would like to have it declared in `group_vars` so if some of hosts have same configuration I doesn't have to edit multiple files.

And I assume thats possible to wrote it like that:

```
variables:
  host1:
    var1: var1val1
  host2:
    var1: var1val1
  host3:
    var1: var1val2
  host4:
    var1: var1val2
```

but thats not a convenient solution as well.

Is there a way in ansible to store variables in such way?

Comment: why cant you try the host_vars and group_vars ?

Comment: Don't know if I understand your question, but I've already tried solution with declaring in `group_vars` and then `host2` have `var1` variable and `host1` doesn't (like in above piece of code). If I misunderstood sth let me know. I wanted to avoid declaring same variables with same values in multiple files - I think it will look the same if I will declare it in `host_vars` in multiple catalogs and files.

Comment: Group variable are attached to groups of hosts, not host, host variables, on the other hands are attached to hosts.

Comment: Also, this is an over complication: `{{ variables[inventory_hostname].var1 }}`. This should actually be wrote plain `{{ var1 }}`

Comment: So basically what you describe here is _I want to create a group `whatever`, this group would have variables in `group_vars`, then I want to assign hosts in this group based on their configuration_. Have you tested that? Is it answering your need?

Comment: Okay - so in ansible directory in `group_vars` I can group hosts from many environments under one group key, assign the variables to that group and they will be available to that host and declared in one place. I will test it, but it looks like what I need.
I don't know if we're always on the same page, but I think that your questions and suggestions led me to a proper documentation - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-many-machines-group-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**Avoid setting two variables for every environment host in many files. Instead, I would like to have it declared in group_vars so if some of the hosts have the same configuration I don't have to edit multiple files.**"*

A: For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[group1_hosts]
host1
host2
```

put the variables into the *group_vars/group1_hosts.yml*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/group1_hosts.yml
var1: var1val1
var2: var2val2
```

Then the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: group1_hosts
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: var1
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [host1] => 
  var1: var1val1
ok: [host2] => 
  var1: var1val1
```

See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) how to override the *group_vars*.

Comment: That's it! I've got into loop of more complex solution cause I didn't knew I can group hosts otherwise than by env. That's nice, thanks to all cause it led me to proper documentation page and how to use it :)